# How to point an additional custom Django admin site to separate templates (whilst retaining the default admin site)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

New here - appreciate this might be a fairly simple problem!

I am creating a custom admin site to run in addition to the default admin (with different functionality). I would like to use a different set of html templates, whilst leaving the default admin unaffected.

I've tried creating a new templates folder, but no changes appear in my custom admin.

In my admin.py:

```py
class CustomAdminSite(AdminSite):
     # can override things here

# create the custom admin site 
custom_admin_site = CustomAdminSite(name='customadmin')
```

How do I use a different set of templates for my custom admin site whilst leaving the default admin unaffected?